# Android: Update TableLayout

Tags: android, search, android-tablelayout

Is there any way to update a table layout after it has been created?
I have a TableLayout that should contain the results of a search. I verified that the results are returned accurately and added to the table but somehow the table doesn't show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling invalidate() on TableLayout after the result set has changed.

Comment: While that is absolutely acceptable as an answer to this, it didnt help me solve the issue. I ended up switching to a ListView which worked like a charm. Thanks!